# Select value from PHP table and pass it to another PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, html-table

The values are from the database. I want to select a row from the table and I want pass those values to the next PHP page called OInfo.php. I tried using Javascript and put those values in textboxes but when I click in the continue button the don't get those values even using the request method. What can I do?

```
<form action="OInfo.php" METHOD="POST">
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<table class="table table-hover table-datatable table-striped table-bordered" id="tableresult">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><center>Sección</center></th>
    <th><center>Espacios Disponibles</center></th>
    <th><center>Tiempo de espera</center></th>
    <th><center>Opciones</center></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

 <!---Start of code--->
<tbody>
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM department where dept_id='$id'";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query);
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
        $list = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row1['dept_schedule'], 0, (strlen($row1['dept_schedule'])+0))));

        foreach($list as $value){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><center>$value</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>20</center></td>";
            echo '<td><center><input type="radio" name="select" value="select">  Seleccionar</center></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    <input type='text' name="schedule" id="schedule" value="<? php $value ?>">

</tbody>
<!---End of code--->
</table>

</div>
    <div class='inputWrapper'>
        <input type='text' name="schedule" id="schedule" >
    </div> 
</div>

</form>

<?php
     echo '<a href="OInfo.php?id='.$data['dept_id'].'"><input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;"></a>';
?>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script>
    $('#tableresult tr').click(function(event) {
        $('td', this).each(function(i) {
            $('.inputWrapper input').eq(i).val(this.textContent);
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Off-topic but look at mysqli / PDO, rather than mysql_ - making this live would be preeeetty insecure.

Comment: your submit button echo should be within the form tag. why is it inside <a tag? Also why do you pass variables via Url?

Comment: `<?php echo $value; ?>` or `<?= $value ?>`

Answer (score 1):

There is space `value="<? php $value ?>">` it should be `value="<?php echo $value ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

```
           **// Comment: Put Everything in input hidden feild and then use on next page ...**
          <table id="example" align="center" cellspacing="0">
            <thead bgcolor="#999999">
                <tr>
                <th>heading1</th>           
                <th>heading2</th>
                <th>heading3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                if(isset($list))
                {
                    $counter = 1;
                    foreach($list as $val)      
                    {   
                      ?>      
                        <form action="OInfo.php" method="post">     
                        <tr>
                        <td>{{$counter++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$val->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$val->mobile}}</td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $val->id}}">
                        <td> 
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Pay" >     
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                       </form>

                       <?php
                    }                                                           
                }
            </tbody>
```